# Snow Leopard 64 bits mode (EFI64 Firmware)

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, mac, firmware, efi

How do I get the EFI64 firmware on my iMac 20" (late 2006) with Intel Core 2 Duo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As there is no EFI64 firmware update, the only option left to know if you have a 64 bits EFI is to run the following command:

```
ioreg -l -p IODeviceTree | grep firmware-abi
```

If the result is "firmware-abi" = <"EFI64">, then you have a 64 bits comptabible EFI.
If the result is "firmware-abi" = <"EFI32">, then you don't have a 64 bits compatible EFI.

This parameter only affects the kernel load by Snow Leopard. You can still run 64 bits applications, bu the kernel will run as 32 bits.

Answer (score 4):

The is no EFI64 firmware upgrade available. Thus, you have to stay with the 32-bit Snow Leopard kernel (but you can use 64-bit Apps anyway).